# how can i concatenate files in linux/unix directory which are generated only on the same day ?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, concatenation, days

cat command command is concatenating all the text files.
I do not want the old files i.e files created on previous days to be concatenated in the output file.
I want only the current day text files concatenation in output file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using find:

```
find . -mtime -1 -type f -exec cat {} >> output.txt \;
```

This will concatenate only files that were **modified** since one day ago till now,
there are other parameters like `atime` (access time) `ctime` (changed time). You need to run the command in the directory, where the files you want to concatenate are located.

update:

Also there is a `-newermt` option for `find`, which will grab files that has been changed or modified since a specific time with a time string like `2017-02-07 13:12:33`:

```
find . -newermt '2017-02-07 13:12:33' -type f -exec cat {} >> output.txt \;
```

Comment: i think it adds all the files accessed  24 hours ago from now. how can i get the current day eg{2/feb/2017} files to be concatenated . but date should not be static declaration..

Comment: @venky513 if my answer helps you could accept the answer by click the √ button, so we both could gain some rep :D